# 2D NSMutableArray in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in IOS and I don't have idea that how to populate my 2D array in `collectionView`.

**How Will I display following in collectionView using Labels.

```
myArray[0]->1,2,3,4,5
myArray[1]->6,7,8,9
myArray[2]->10,11,12,15


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

// What to call here as this is 2D?

return self.myArray.count;

}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *simpleId= @"CollectionViewCell";
TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleId forIndexPath:indexPath];

//What to write here ? Cell contain 1 Label
}
```

Comment: I guess:`collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` `return [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] count];`, in `numberOfSection`: `return [self.myArray count]`, in `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`: `NSString *item = [[self.myArray objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath section] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` ?

Comment: [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
This gives error of "control returns to non void function"

Comment: @SyedMunimRaza welcome to stackoverflow and please check my below answer.. Hope this will help you to get resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this (as @Larme suggested)-

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   NSString *simpleId= @"CollectionViewCell";
   TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleId forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.lbl.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

   return cell;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

     return self.myArray.count;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] count]
}
```

In your 2D array **myArray[0]** is first section consist 5 value, **myArray[1]** is second section consist 4 values and **myArray[2]** is second section consist 5 values. So 2D Array can be easily managed by `numberOfSection` and `numberOfItemsInSection` methods. Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks Alot Larme and Dev.RK

Comment: Dev.RK there is a minor issue. 
`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   
    return [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}`

**In this section it is not incrementing it always remains on 0**

Comment: try to NSLog [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] count] and [self.myArray objectAtIndex:section] first will print size and second line will print array..